# Add my site to trusted sites zone and disable protected mode for trusted sites programmatically

Tags: asp.net, protected-mode, trusted-sites

Is there any way to add my site to trusted sites zone and disable protected mode for trusted sites programmatically?

When I browse my site, it should be added to trusted sites automatically and at the same time protected mode for trusted sites need to be disabled.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having trusted / untrusted sites?

Comment: My application contains an activex component and some ftp download, For this to work in elevated user access control levels i need to disable protected mode in ie. For this purpose iam adding my site to trusted sites zone and disabling protected mode. it will be better if this is set automatically instead of end user setting this